# Delete the characters of a line between two limiters including themselves

Tags: sed, delimiter

After hacking I need clean some code add to first line on too many files.

```
<?php $somevar = 'some code....... ?><?php
```

I need clean between and include `<?php $somevar` and `?>` because latest `<?php` can to be different such `<html` and others.

If use this I need two steeps, because not clean delimiters. I need delete delimiters also.

```
sed -i.bak 's/\(<?php $drnrwsrl\).*\(?>\)/\1\2/' file.php
```

Result

```
<?php $drnrwsrl?><?php
```

Instead of what I want

```
<?php
```

Comment: Can you re-edit your input line to include your actual output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using BRE without backreference:

```
sed -i.bak 's/<?php \$somevar[^>]*><?php/<?php/' file.php
```

To apply only to first line:

```
sed -i.bak '1s/<?php \$somevar[^>]*><?php/<?php/' file.php
```

Comment: A lot of tahnks. Best and more clean, because i need only check on first line

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sed -i.bak -E 's/(<\?php.*\(?>)(<\?php)/\2/' file.php
```

Comment: `sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 29: ) ó \) desemparejados`